# Company Crud with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, create-react-app, crud

I'm trying to create a CRUD function with React Redux. When I put `const {id} = useParams();` and  `<h1 className="display-3 my-5 text-center">Edit Company{id} </h1>`in the EditCompany.js the webpage is blank but there is no error. Then when I remove the useParams in the code, the webpage shows the table.

The empty webpage [empty webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eTW5.png)

My desired webpage [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNcxw.png)

This is my codes:

EditCompany.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link} from "react-router-dom";
import{useParams} from "react-router-dom";

const EditCompany = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
        return(
        <div className="container">
        <h1 className="display-3 my-5 text-center">
            Edit Company{id}
            </h1>
         <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 shadow mx-auto p-5">
             <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                type="text" placeholder="Name" className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Description(optional)"
                className="form-control"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="VIP"
                className="form-control"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Update Company" className="btn btn-dark" />
                <Link to="/" 
                className="btn btn-danger ml-3">Cancel</Link>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    );
};

export default EditCompany;
```

App.js code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Index.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

import "./App.css"; 
import AddCompany from "./components/AddCompany";
import EditCompany from "./components/EditCompany";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const App=()=> {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ToastContainer />
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component ={()=><Home/>} /> 
        <Route path="/add">
        <AddCompany/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/edit/:id">
        <EditCompany />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ap
```

Comment: The first image 'blank' is `/edit` route, with NO `id`.
It's blank because there's no `/edit` Route.

Comment: @AmrEraky But when I change the URL to edit/1 it is still empty

Comment: What is the version of react-route-dom you use?
It works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wright-ot2pts
change link

Comment: @AmrEraky here it is    
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"

Comment: @AmrEraky how to run the code in the CodeSandBox?